# How to run server.js on client-side?

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

Can anyone explain me how I can run the server.js on client-side. Like I have index.html page and I've a button in it and I want to generate PDF on button click event and pass dynamic data to PDF. I've literally no idea about node.js. Any kind of help is appreciated. Sorry if the question is duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you don't. Node.js is a back end and the server.js file you have should not run on the browser. If you need the functionality on server.js after the first load you need to use something like ajax to communicate with the server. Or you could try to get your server code to run in the browser, but that may not work for all browsers and is probably a bad practice.